# How to run a nuxt generated website from filesystem?

Tags: file, vue.js, nuxt.js, serverless

When I run a nuxt generated vue website from file system, with no server, I get `GET file:///_nuxt/...` with status `(failed)`

How to run a nuxt generated vuejs app from filesystem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
module.exports = {
  ...
  mode: 'spa',
  router: {
    ...
    mode: 'hash'
  },
  build: {
    extend (config) {
      ...
      config.output.publicPath = './_nuxt/'
```

**Update:** let me explain this step by step.

1) `mode: 'spa'` -- no server-side rendering (only client-side navigation).

2) `router mode: 'hash'` -- switch from `history` mode, that requires a server to fake filesystem calls, to totally client based approach where all urls prefixed with `#`.

3) `config.output.publicPath` -- this changes the assumption, that all assets are stored at the root. Which is actually the root cause of the `file:///_nuxt/...` error.

Comment: THANK YOU, I have spent so long trying to make this work.